# Loading Facebook's Javascript SDK safely without overriding already loaded SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

We are developing a Shopify app which is loading FB JS SDK. We load our app's JS using the Shopify's ScriptTag API which injects our JS into the Shopify's site.

Everything works well when our's is the sole app which loads the FB JS SDK. But here is the issue:

If there is another app or the shopify store itself loads the FB SDK and calls FB.init, we face 2 problems:

1. We want to trigger our code's window.fbAsyncInit function. Whats the best way to detect if fbAsyncInit has already executed.
2. Can we call FB.init again with our AppID? What are the side effects of doing so? If we cant re initialize with our AppID is there any workaround this problem where our app can co exist with an app which is already loaded?

Comment: about 2: did you test it? what did you find out? either way, i would say it´s very bad practice to have 2 app (ids) for one single website

Comment: about 1: ....set a global var?

Comment: @luschn about 1: I don't control the script which might load the FB sdk before my script. So I cant set a global var. All I can do check if window.FB is defined or not. 

about 2: I tested with one script which loads FB but does not pass  AppId to init. So it works. But there might be scripts that might set the AppId. I dont know what to do then